# How to pass `prometheus.io/scrape` value through `--set` parameter in helm install

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Using https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/elasticsearch-exporter and trying to pass the part below via `--set` parameter but so far no luck.

```
podAnnotations: 
  prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
  prometheus.io/port: "9108"
```

so far I tried `helm install --name prometheus-elasticsearch-exporter stable/elasticsearch-exporter` with

```
--set podAnnotations."prometheus.io/scrape"=true,podAnnotations."prometheus.io/port"=9108

--set podAnnotations[0]."prometheus.io/scrape"=true,podAnnotations[0]."prometheus.io/port"=9108

--set podAnnotations."prometheus\.io\/scrape"=true,podAnnotations."prometheus\.io\/port"=9108

--set podAnnotations={"prometheus.io/scrape":true,"prometheus.io/port":9108}

--set podAnnotations={"prometheus.io/scrape"=true\,"prometheus.io/port"=9108}
```

and unfortunately, none of those worked.

More details can be found in [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/using_helm.md#the-format-and-limitations-of---set)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
--set-string podAnnotations."prometheus\.io/scrape"=true \
--set-string podAnnotations."prometheus\.io/port"=9108
```

You need to escape the annotation key strings correctly, as described precisely in the doc you linked:

> Similarly, you can escape dot sequences as well, which may come in handy when charts use the `toYaml` function to parse annotations, labels and node selectors. The syntax for `--set nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/role"=master` becomes
>
> ```
> nodeSelector:
>   kubernetes.io/role: master
> ```

You should use `set-string` instead of `set` because you want the annotation values to be strings rather than boolean `true` and number `9018`.

Here's the result I'm getting using those flags:

```
$ helm template . \
  --set-string podAnnotations."prometheus\.io/scrape"=true \
  --set-string podAnnotations."prometheus\.io/port"=9108 \
  | grep -C 5 annotations
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch-exporter
        release: "release-name"
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/port: "9108"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"

    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked like a charm. it looks like even escaping as `"prometheus\.io\/scrape"` and `"prometheus\.io\/port"` works. So simply the issue was not using `set-string`. Thank you very much!